# Como ajustar a largura do datatable jquery às telas com resoluções maiores

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, jquery-datatables

Estou tendo problemas ao exibir meu datatable (vazio) em telas com resoluções maiores. Já tentei usar a classe `table-responsive-lg`, mas ela atrapalha a responsividade aplicada pela classe `table-responsive`, isto é, não consigo usar as duas ao mesmo tempo.

A classe `table-responsive` faz com que o datatable não exceda aos limites da largura da página, pois ele cria uma barra de rolagens. Se no lugar da classe `table-responsive` eu utilizar a classe `table-responsive-lg`, corrige o problema, mas aí, em certo momentos em que eu abro a página com resoluções menores, o datatable salta pra fora e excede à largura da página. Então abandonei a ideia de usar a classe `table-responsive-lg`.

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<table id="dtFinanceiroIndex" class="table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered center-header table-vcenter" cellspacing="0" style=" width: 100% !important;">
    <thead class="bg-blue-grey-100">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                    <input id="dt-financeiro-selectable-all" class="selectable-all" type="checkbox">
                    <label></label>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>
                Tipo de Controle Financeiro
            </th>
            <th>
                Núm. do Documento
            </th>
            <th>
                Valor do Documento
            </th>
            <th>
                Cliente/Fornecedor
            </th>
            <th>
                Situação
            </th>
            <th>
                Ações
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()

Ex:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( ... );

setTimeout(function(){
   table.columns.adjust().draw();
},2000)
```

Comment: Tive um problema parecido e consegui resolver assim

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Rodrigo Zem, mas não funcionou :(

Comment: Seu datatable está com o a largura das colunas definidas para auto?

Comment: "autoWidth": false    @MasterJR, veja se consegue agora. Fiz uma alteração no código  da resposta ...